Identify if the following are Markov processes
I'm taking the MIT 18.S096 2013 OCW and stumbled across the following problem: identify whether the following are Markov processes:
(d) $X_0 = 0$ and $X_{t+1} = X_t+ Z_tZ_{t-1} \cdot Z_0$ for $t\geq0$, where $Z_t$ are i.i.d. random variables with log-normal distribution.
(e) $X_0 = 0$ and $X_{t+1} = X_t + W_t + W_{t−1} + \ldots + W_0$ for $t \geq 0$, where $W_t$ are i.i.d. random variables with normal distribution.
The course notes define the Markov property discretely: $P(X_{t+1} = i | X_0, \ldots X_t) = P(X_{t+1} = i | X_t)$. I'm assuming we must prove some sort of continuous analogue, namely $P(a \leq X_{t+1} \leq b | X_0, \ldots X_t) = P(a \leq X_{t+1} \leq b | X_t)$. My confusion lies in how we are supposed to find both of these values for these processes.
In (e), I've found that if you have $X_0, \ldots, X_t$, you are able to also find $W_0, \ldots, W_{t-1}$, which means you can express $X_{t+1}$ probabilities very nicely, in terms of just one normal variable $W_t$. However, I'm lost when trying to find probabilities for $X_{t+1}$ just when given $X_t$: it seems like this shouldn't be the same as a nice, singular normal distribution, but I'm having trouble proving it.
In (d), I'm a bit more lost. I've found that $X_{t+1} = Z_0(Z_0Z_1 + Z_1Z_2 + \ldots + Z_{t+1}Z_t)$, so it similarly seems that having all of $X_0, \ldots, X_t$ should give you more information; although I'm having trouble showing that.
Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

I think what you want for the continuous space Markov property is $$\mathbb E [X_{t+1} \chi_A | X_{t}]= \mathbb E [X_{t+1} \chi_A | X_{t}, \dots, X_0]$$ for $\chi_A$ indicating a $\mathcal F_{t+1}$ measurable event. Here I’m using $\mathcal F$ to denote the filtration, for you $\mathcal F_t$ is the sigma algebra generated by $X_t$.
